# Can't delete io_service object (Boost)

Tags: c++, boost, websocket

I have error on close websocket connection.

```
NetworkConnector::NetworkConnector()
{
    _ios = new boost::asio::io_service();
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*_ios);

    _sock = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(*_ios);

    boost::asio::connect(*_sock, resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{ SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT }));
    _ws = new beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&>(*_sock);
    _ws->handshake(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_SERVICE_NAME);
}

...

NetworkConnector::~NetworkConnector()
{
    _ws->close(beast::websocket::close_code::normal);
    delete _sock;
    delete _ws;

    _ios->stop();
    delete _ios;
}
```

The error occurs in destructor of NetworkConnector class. (when _ios object is deleting from memory) (Sorry for bad English)

[image: Memory read error]

Comment: did you join the I/O thread (if any)?

Comment: I created method for send/receive data, but error in destructor occurs even don't use this method.

Comment: I cannot see any error. Post the error please. There can be lots of reasons for "error on close".